# Python Requests 403 on Linux but works from Windows

Tags: python, linux, web-scraping, python-requests

I am currently experiencing a strange issue with web scraping, for some reason the identical code works from my PC (Status Code: 200) but not from a Ubuntu 16.04 Server (Status Code: 403) running the exact same python version.

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get('https://zooqle.com/', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
print(response.status_code)
```

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Try to set the user agent header to some typical browser.

Comment: With web scraping, there is a very real possibility that you'll get banned for using too much of their bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

The answer might be the firewall outbound rule, it is blocking you, I've tested your code on my Ubuntu 16.04 with Python 2.7.13, and received the 200 status.

Check your inbound and outbound rules with:

```
sudo iptables -L -n
```

My iptable looks like this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

I've just posted here for you to compare with yours and correct your Linux firewall, focus on the ACCEPT/REJECT requests.

Comment: Everything seems Good, my only guess is that it is being blocked by the VPS provider.

Comment: That is possible too.

Comment: I tried the same thing using selenium web-driver which resulted in the following page asking for a CAPTCHA which isn't shown when accessed via any browser from windows. 

http://prntscr.com/g5gr1a

I'll try enabling cookies and report accordingly

Comment: Still no Luck, VPS provider confirmed that they allow all traffic, my final guess is that my IP/location is blacklisted from cloud-flare or the site itself hence asking me for a captcha each time i access it (which cannot be bypassed from my knowledge)

Answer (score 0):

Conclusion: Site is being blocked by ISP.

Resolution: Used a Web Proxy and web scraping it to get the required data